# Function that accepts two numbers and returns a random number between the two numbers. (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript

Been learning JavaScript for a few weeks now, and I am trying to write a function that prompts the user for 2 numbers and the generate a random number between them. I wrote this code,

```
function randomInt(min,max) {

var min = prompt( "Enter a number." );
var max = prompt( "Enter another number." );
var randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;

return randNum;

}
alert(randomInt());
```

It does prompt me for the numbers but it generates a random number not a number between the two that I've entered. Like I enter 5 and 20 and it returns 31 or 2 but when tried,

```
var min = 5;
var max = 20;
```

It works, actually gives me a number between 5 and 20, not sure why though. It seems like a simple task but just stumped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `prompt()` function returns **strings**, not numbers. You can force the values to be interpreted as numbers with the unary `+` operator:

```
    var min = +prompt("Enter a number.");
    var max = +prompt( "Enter another number." );
```

Without that, the outer `+` operator will preferentially perform a string concatenation operation because the right-hand operand (`min`) is a string. That is, in this expression:

```
    Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min
```

The `-` operator in `max - min` will cause that to be done properly as a numeric subtraction. However, the outer `+` by which the minimum value is added back to the random number will perform a string concatenation and not a numeric addition if `min` is a string.  Thus you'll end up with a random integer between 0 and the implied range, concatenated onto the minimum value (as a string).

Comment: What about using parseInt(string).

Comment: @fubbe that's great if you want integers, and also if you don't care that `parseInt()` will return `32` from `32foofoofoo` because it ignores trailing noise.

Comment: Anyway the + is some sort of implicit typecasting here?

Comment: @fubbe it's the unary `+` operator, which always forces its operand to be treated as a number. It's like unary `-` without changing the numeric sign.